# Return documents ID in snapshot firestore JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Coding and Firestore ,For some reason I can't get it right.
I'm want to return `doc.id` but the output I got is **undefined** it seems like it didn't return any data

output of `console.log(doc.id)` is `hqyWHGrVHvopdyVACRkn`
output of `ID` is **undefined**

```
const getProductDocId = async (productName1) =>{
  try{
    const ID = await firestore().collection('product').where('productName' ,'==', productName1).get().then(snapshot=>{
      snapshot.docs.every(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id + " THIS is DOC.ID")
        return doc.id
      })
    })
    
    console.log(ID)
 
   }catch(error){
     console.log("Error @ Get Prdocut ID  " + error)
   }finally{
     console.log(ID)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied `await` in wrong way. If a `Promise` is passed to an `await` expression, it waits for the `Promise` to be fulfilled and returns the fulfilled value.

```
try {
  const snapshot = await firestore()
    .collection("product")
    .where("productName", "==", productName1)
    .get();
  let id = null;
  snapshot.docs.every((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id + " THIS is DOC.ID");
    id = doc.id;
  });
  console.log(id);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error @ Get Prdocut ID  " + error);
} finally {
  console.log(id);
}
```